# Odoo 17 enterprise Error When I click on cash flow report

Tags: odoo, odoo-17

I am trying to run cash flow statement report from report menu in Odoo

Once I click it I am getting this error message as below.

all other reports are working fine without any issue, expect the cash flow statment report. how do I fix this issue ?

```
RPC_ERROR
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\http.py", line 1765, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\http.py", line 1792, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\http.py", line 1996, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 222, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\http.py", line 722, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 24, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 20, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\api.py", line 468, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\api.py", line 453, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\addons\account_reports\models\account_report.py", line 4306, in get_report_information
    'lines': self._get_lines(options, all_column_groups_expression_totals=all_column_groups_expression_totals, warnings=warnings),
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\addons\account_reports\models\account_report.py", line 2091, in _get_lines
    dynamic_lines = self._get_dynamic_lines(options, all_column_groups_expression_totals, warnings=warnings)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\addons\account_reports\models\account_report.py", line 2449, in _get_dynamic_lines
    return self.env[self.custom_handler_model_name]._dynamic_lines_generator(self, options, all_column_groups_expression_totals, warnings=warnings)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\addons\account_reports\models\account_cash_flow_report.py", line 16, in _dynamic_lines_generator
    report_data = self._get_report_data(report, options, layout_data)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\addons\account_reports\models\account_cash_flow_report.py", line 57, in _get_report_data
    for aml_groupby_account in self._get_liquidity_moves(report, options, currency_table_query, payment_account_ids, cashflow_tag_ids):
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\addons\account_reports\models\account_cash_flow_report.py", line 362, in _get_liquidity_moves
    self._cr.execute(' UNION ALL '.join(queries), params)
  File "C:\odooenterprise\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 332, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 28: ...            AND account_move_line.account_id NOT IN ((), ())
                                                                  ^


The above server error caused the following client error:
OwlError: The following error occurred in onWillStart: "Odoo Server Error"
    at wrapError (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:1044:77)
    at onWillStart (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:1050:117)
    at AccountReport.setup (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:18330:86)
    at new ComponentNode (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:1002:202)
    at http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:1540:6
    at ControllerComponent.template (eval at compile (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:1500:374), <anonymous>:11:27)
    at Fiber._render (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:940:96)
    at Fiber.render (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:939:6)
    at ComponentNode.initiateRender (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:1007:47)

Caused by: RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    at makeErrorFromResponse (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:2874:163)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/841ab3a/web.assets_web.min.js:2878:13)
```

Is this error related to database? or coding and assets files ?
Any suggestions how to resolve this ?

Comment: That's probably something you should ask on the [github issues](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues) of Odoo.

Comment: I found the issue